# CURL command works in command prompt but not as batch file

Tags: batch-file, curl, cmd, command-prompt, home-assistant

I have read every other thread on this topic and none of them seem to illuminate what is happening.

I am trying to send a CURL command to my Home Assistant instance by executing a batch file.

```
C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer token removed" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ \"entity_id\":\"script.fan_turnon\" }' http://192.168.1.XXX:8123/api/services/script/turn_on
```

This command works flawlessly in the command prompt but as a .bat or .cmd a window briefly opens and then disappears. I have attempted to add pause to the end but the same result. What have I stuffed up?

Note: personally identifying information removed from code

Comment: if any of your redacted strings contains a symbol, especially `%` you may have problems. Try posting those strings, replacing alphamerics with `abc123`.

Comment: Open the command prompt and run the script from there instead of double-clicking on the script. The window will stay open and you'll be able to read the error message that you get.

Comment: @SomethingDark it says `curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 1:
}'
 ^`

Comment: Solved - it was the single quotes, needed to be double quotes

Answer (score 1):

Solved - it was the single quotes, needed to be double quotes